# Haskell getting elements out of the list

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, split

How can I split a list over and over again while working on it's second part? For example:

```
recursiveFun list = do  
    ...
    newlist = snd $ splitAt 2 list
    recursiveFun newlist
```

Will never go through the list,

edit: source code

```
translatePixelsToMatrix :: B.ByteString -> Int -> Int -> [Matrix Word8] -> [Matrix Word8]
translatePixelsToMatrix bytes columns rows mat = do
  let mat = matrix rows columns (\(i, j) -> (B.index bytes $ toEnum $ (i - 1) + (j - 1) * columns)) : mat
  let contents = snd $ B.splitAt (toEnum (rows * columns)) bytes
  if not $ B.null contents
    then translatePixelsToMatrix contents rows columns mat
    else mat
```

First argument of

```
translatePixelsToMatrix bytes columns rows mat
```

is the same in every call of the function, but I want to drop n first elements with

```
      let contents = snd $ B.splitAt (toEnum (rows * columns)) bytes
      then translatePixelsToMatrix contents rows columns mat
```

Comment: When does the function stop?

Comment: What is the original problem that you are trying to solve? I think that your proposed solution here is probably not the best way to do it in Haskell.

Comment: You can use `drop 2` instead of `snd $ splitAt 2`. The problem is that when you call your function with an empty list, `splitAt 2 []` returns `([],[])` and you then call your function again with `[]`. You need a case to deal with that

Comment: You can, of course, do this using primitive recursion. I suggest using existing work, e.g. [`chunksOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.3/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf).

Comment: I’m trying to understand why you’re in a monad here (the list monad). It doesn’t really make any sense

Comment: Every element of a list represents a single picture of digit. It's for lab project, I wanted to do neural networks but ended up reading and printing packed data of drawn digits